# Cannot find custom Launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use a custom `launch` file from http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/RemoteMapping and  no matter what I've tried, I can't get the launch file to show without launching it from the folder it exists in.

#Works

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src/rtabmap_ros/launch
$ roslaunch freenect_throttle.launch
```

#Does Not Work

```
$ cd ~/
$ roslaunch freenect_throttle.launch
```

In fact, in the terminal if I type `$ roslaunch freen` and hit **tab** twice I'm given two freenect options but not the launch file I'm looking for.

I've tried manually putting in the launch file:

```
$ roslaunch freenect_throttle.launch
[freenect_throttle.launch] is not a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

`ROS` is sourced, `catkin_ws` is sourced, all my other apps work but this is being a stickler.

I've also tried:

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/
$ catkin_make
```

and a step further:

```
$ catkin_make install
```

and then resourced the `setup.bash`

```
$ source devel/setup.bash
```

and still no luck. What am I missing?

## ** EDIT ** *for Thomas D*

$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros freenect_throttle.launch
[freenect_throttle.launch] is neither a launch file in package [rtabmap] nor is [rtabmap] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

So I went back and rebuilt `rtabmap`

```
$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
[  5%] Built target rtabmap_utilite
[  6%] Built target res_tool
[ 39%] Built target rtabmap_core
[ 86%] Built target rtabmap_gui
[ 88%] Built target rtabmap
[ 89%] Built target consoleApp
[ 89%] Built target imagesJoiner
[ 90%] Built target extractObject
[ 90%] Built target camera
[ 90%] Built target rgbd_camera
[ 91%] Built target stereoEval
[ 92%] Built target databaseViewer
[ 92%] Built target epipolar_geometry
[ 92%] Built target odometryViewer
[ 92%] Built target dataRecorder
[ 93%] Built target calibration
[ 93%] Built target bow_mapping
[ 95%] Built target rgbd_mapping
[ 98%] Built target wifi_mapping
[100%] Built target noEventsExample
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Up-to-date: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/rtabmap-0.11/RTABMapConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/rtabmap-0.11/RTABMapConfigVersion.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/share/rtabmap/package.xml

...

-- Up-to-date: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/bin/rtabmap-odometryViewer
-- Up-to-date: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/bin/rtabmap-dataRecorder
-- Up-to-date: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/bin/rtabmap-calibration
```

I re-sourced but saw no change. So the bigger problem has become that I cannot run `rtabmap` via ros! Do `rtabmap` and `rtabmap_ros` need to be in different catkin folders?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232641/cannot-find-custom-launch-file/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-04-22**:
In which directory do you end up (`pwd`) after a `roscd rtabmap_ros` ?? Also, could you post the output of `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` please? This may be a workspace overlaying issue.

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-22**:
`pwd` for `roscd rtabmap_ros` is `~/catkin_ws/src/rtabmap_ros` and `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is */home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks*

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-04-23**:
OK, these look good. I was gonna ask about `roslaunch rtabmap_ros [tab-tab]` but, reading the comments underneath Thomas' answer, I think you already did that.

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-23**:
Yep. This is a tricky one which makes me think it's something very simple. I may need to start from scratch on a fresh install but I'm hoping someone will enlighten me. After all, knowing the root cause is much more valuable to me than being ignorant to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For this particular situation, here is what worked for me.

**Install rtabmap first:**

```
$ cd ~
$ git clone https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap.git rtabmap
$ cd rtabmap/build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/catkin_ws/devel ..
$ make -j4
$ make install
```

the `DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is what solved my issue. I don't know why creating my *own catkin_ws* did not work but I suspect I was missing something simple.

**Install rtabmap_ros second:**

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws
$ git clone https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros.git src/rtabmap_ros
$ catkin_make
```

in this second step you've used the *catkin_ws* folder that was created by the `rtabmap` install. I added my `freenect_throttle.launch` to `catkin_ws/src/rtabmap_ros/launch` folder and then re-ran `catkin_make` inside the parent `catkin_ws` folder.

All documentation for `rtabmap`, `rtabmap_ros`, and `` can be found in the following links:

- [rtabmap homepage](http://introlab.github.io/rtabmap/)
- [Installing rtabmap](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Installation)
- [Installing rtabmap_ros](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros)
- [Using rtabmap with a remote machine](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/RemoteMapping)

*Note: You get an issue on the freenect_throttle.launch when you first run it because one of the xml comments is not closed correctly, close the comment and it will run fine. I've attached what the corrected launch file below*

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find freenect_launch)/launch/freenect.launch">
     <arg name="depth_registration" value="True" />
  </include>

  <arg name="rate"  default="5"/>
  <arg name="decimation"  default="1"/> 
  <!-- Reduce the image size, e.g., 2 means "width/2 x height/2". -->

  <!-- Use same nodelet used by Freenect/OpenNI -->
  <group ns="camera">
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="data_throttle" args="load rtabmap_ros/data_throttle camera_nodelet_manager" output="screen">
      <param name="rate" type="double" value="$(arg rate)"/>
      <param name="decimation" type="int" value="$(arg decimation)"/>

      <remap from="rgb/image_in"       to="rgb/image_rect_color"/>
      <remap from="depth/image_in"     to="depth_registered/image_raw"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info_in" to="rgb/camera_info"/>

      <remap from="rgb/image_out"       to="data_throttled_image"/>
      <remap from="depth/image_out"     to="data_throttled_image_depth"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info_out" to="data_throttled_camera_info"/>
    </node>
  </group>      
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) with karma: 396 on 2016-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try `roslaunch  rtabmap_ros freenect_throttle.launch`. You seem to be missing the package name that the launch file exists in.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2016-04-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-22**:
No such luck. I added an edit to the bottom of my original question with details.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2016-04-22**:
In the edit it looks like you tried to use `roslaunch` with the `rtabmap` package and not the `rtabmap_ros` package. Try the exact command I gave in the answer and see if that helps.

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-22**:
My mistake. I had actually tried both when I tried it. Like the freenect_throttle.launch, double pressing the tab key lists no values. If I double tab after `roslaunch`  (a space at the end) I get 141 possibilities, such items as: `octomap`, `openni_camera`, `rosbag`, `pcl_ros`, etc...

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2016-04-22**:
You did `. ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` then `roslaunch rtabmap_ros freenect_throttle.launch`? What do you get if you run `. ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash; roscd rtabmap; ls launch`?

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-22**:
`Permission denied ls: cannot access launch: No such file or directory`. I tried it with `roscd rtabmap_ros` and I get a list of 12 files, one of which is `freenect_throttle.launch`

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-24**:
I solved it. +1 for your helpful efforts.